# display certain image depending on string value return from firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to display a certain image in a user cell depending on  account type so firebase contains a account type: person's account i would like to display a  persons account image and if it contains account type: business account i would like to display a business account image.

I've tried this but it doesn't work

class UserCell: UITableViewCell {

```
 func setAccountTypeImage(){ 
    let AccountimageView = UIImageView()

    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


        if snapshot.hasChild("Person's Account User"){

            AccountimageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon-72x72")
        }else{

            if snapshot.hasChild("Business Account User"){

                AccountimageView.image = UIImage(named: "B icon-72x72")

            }
        }
    })
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
```

super.layoutSubviews()

let AccountTypeImage: UIImageView = {
        let AccountimageView = UIImageView()

```
    AccountimageView.image = UIImage(named: "Grape")

    AccountimageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // the code below makes image a circle
    //the value of 24 comes from half the width/hieght anchor constant of 48
    AccountimageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    AccountimageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    AccountimageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill




    return AccountimageView

}()


override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

addSubview(AccountTypeImage)

```
    AccountTypeImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    AccountTypeImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    AccountTypeImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    AccountTypeImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

}
```

Comment: You are talking about a distinction between female, or male, however your code only does a distinction between person or business accounts. Maybe an example screenshot of the Firebase database structure would help.

Comment: What doesnt work? btw "AccountimageView" what r u doing with it after?

Comment: @vlad Pulichev - i updated the question , it now shows  the "grape" image in the simulator , though when comment out the  AccountimageView.image = UIImage(named: "Grape") code it comes up with no image when i would inspect it to check firebase and show either a business account image or a persons account image?